# Orientation issue while presenting Modal ViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

**Current scenario:**

Right now I am showing a `UIViewController` using a `segue` with the style `Modal` and presentation `Sheet`. This Modal gets its `superview` bounds change, in order to have the dimensions I want, like this:

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    self.view.superview.bounds = WHBoundsRect;
}
```

The only allowed orientations are `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft` and `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight`. Since the Modal has some `TextFields` and the keyboard would be over the Modal itself, I am changing its `center` so it moves a bit to the top.

**The problem:**

What I am noticing right now, is that I am unable to work with the Y coordinate. In order for it move vertically (remember it's on landscape) I need to work with the X. The problem is that when it's `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft` I need to come with a negative X. And when it's `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight` I need to come with a positive X. So it seems that the [X/Y Coordinate System](http://www.we-r-here.com/cad/tutorials/level_3/images/xy_axis.gif) is "glued" to the top left corner while in Portrait and when an orientation occurs, it's still there:

[image]

**What I have done**

So I have something like this:

```
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
NSInteger newX = 0.0f;

if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
{
  // Logic for calculating the negative X.
}
else
{
  // Logic for calculating the positive X.
}
```

It works exactly like I want, but it seems a very fragile implementation. Am I missing something? Is this the expected behaviour?

Comment: Can you explain me why are you doing self.view.superview.bounds = WHBoundsRect;?

Comment: @AlessandroOrrù "This Modal gets its superview bounds change, in order to have the dimensions I want"

Comment: Got it, didn't see that the modal had a superview with the same size between the modal view and the container UIWindow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

I wrote a test project, you can find it [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8211801/ModalTest.zip)

Here is the interesting part, the modal view controller subclass code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillAppear:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    self.view.superview.bounds = WHBoundsRect;
}

- (void)keyboardWillAppear:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    CGRect keyboardFrame = [notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];

    // Calculate keyboard frame in superview coordinates.
    // Origin will be in the upper left corner of the superview, so keyboard will have a negative x origin.
    CGRect keyboardFrameInSuperviewCoordinates = [self.view.superview convertRect:keyboardFrame fromView:nil];

    NSLog(@"Superview bounds: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.superview.bounds));
    NSLog(@"Keyboard frame in screen coordinates: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(keyboardFrame));
    NSLog(@"Keyboard frame in superview coordinates: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(keyboardFrameInSuperviewCoordinates));

    // The keyboard and the superview lay directly in a window, so we should do the math on window coordinates
    // Converting  to the superview system takes account of rotation, so now y is relative to current orientation
    CGRect windowCoordinatesInSuperviewSystem = [self.view.superview convertRect:self.view.superview.window.bounds fromView:nil];

    NSLog(@"Window frame in superview coords: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(windowCoordinatesInSuperviewSystem));


    // We calculate for how much the superview is hidden by the keyboard
    CGFloat hiddenPartHeight = CGRectGetMaxY(self.view.superview.bounds)-CGRectGetMinY(keyboardFrameInSuperviewCoordinates);
    NSLog(@"Superview is hidden by keyboard for %.0f points", hiddenPartHeight);

    // Now we just have to shift the superview frame to the top by 'hiddenPartHeight'.

    // Last step: calculate new superview frame in super-superview coordinate system.
    // To do that, we convert the superview frame relative to its coordinate system to super-superview coordinate system.
    CGRect superviewNewFrameInItsOwnCoordinateSystem = CGRectOffset(self.view.superview.bounds, 0, -hiddenPartHeight);
    CGRect superviewAbsoluteFrame = [self.view.superview convertRect:superviewNewFrameInItsOwnCoordinateSystem toView:self.view.superview.superview];

    NSLog(@"Superview new frame in its own coords: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(superviewNewFrameInItsOwnCoordinateSystem));
    NSLog(@"Superview new frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(superviewAbsoluteFrame));

    self.view.superview.frame = superviewAbsoluteFrame;
}
```

Comment: I see, I was using `self.view.window.view` here `CGRect superviewAbsoluteFrame = [self.view.superview convertRect:superviewNewFrameInItsOwnCoordinateSystem toView:self.view.superview.superview];` instead of `self.view.superview.superview`.

Comment: You could went with `CGRectIntersection(self.view.superview.bounds, keyboardFrameInSuperviewCoordinates);` as well.

Comment: @JackyBoy yes I agree, but they are a bit different. With my solution if view is too small (so rects don't intersect) it gets attached to the keyboard anyway (so pushed bottom). With CGRectIntersection if it is too small it stays still. Choose your favorite solution :)